# Problem with CSS grid image scaling on smaller sizes and image heights

Tags: css

I'm doing uneven grid image like this with bootstrap 4

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
    <img src="images/dummy_image1.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <img src="images/dummy_image2.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    <img src="images/dummy_image3.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
    <img src="images/dummy_image4.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

The images are all equal height, the problem is when resize to MD for example, browser is rounding and images height becomes different (one 401px the other 403px) and in the result it brakes the layout.
See the image.
[image]

Comment: What about putting .col into .row classes ? <div class='row'>[2 .col here]</div><div class='row'>[2 .col here]</div>

Comment: Indeed, these are **separate rows** and should be structured as such.

Comment: Use max height for images or you can also use bootstrap d-flex class to create your grid. or use two div.row with their columns to make the grid

Comment: There is a div container with class row, is not that

Answer (score 0):

I guess your markup should look similar to that:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-5"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Take a look please - maybe it will work as expected for you :)

Comment: There is already container and a row classes in parent divs. Splitting them in two div maybe would help but unfortunately can't do that, as the content is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the issue for me

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:  flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```